# React SetState to update An Array and save to Firestore

Tags: reactjs

I working on an e-commerce site, where I have a cart array

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

// Add Product to cart
  const addProduct = (product) => {
    const exist = cart.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist) {
      setCart(
        cart.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
        )
      );
      setDoc(
        doc(firebaseFirestore, "users", user?.uid!),
        { cart: cart },
        { merge: true }
      )
        .then(() => console.log("done"))
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error"));
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
      chakraToast({
        status: "success",
        title: `Product updated with a new quantity`,
        isClosable: true,
        containerStyle: {
          fontSize: "12.5px",
        },
        variant: "subtle",
        position: "bottom-right",
      });
    } else {
      setCart([...cart, { ...product, qty: 1 }]);
      setDoc(
        doc(firebaseFirestore, "users", user?.uid!),
        { cart: arrayUnion(...cart) },
        { merge: true }
      )
        .then(() => console.log("done"))
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error"));
      chakraToast({
        status: "success",
        title: "Product added successfully",
        isClosable: true,
        containerStyle: {
          fontSize: "12.5px",
        },
        variant: "subtle",
        position: "bottom-right",
      });
      console.log("Cart First Instance", cart);
      console.log(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    }
  };
```

The `AddProduct` function adds objects to the cart Array... The object added must be saved in Firestore DB. On the first click of the button, it sends an empty Array to firestore, because the cart is empty. On the second Click, it sends the First object. On Subsequent clicks, it like it's one step backward.

I also did this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")!);
    console.log(cart);
  }, [cart]);
```

Question: How do I get the `cart` value on the First Click and save it to firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cart state wont update instantly so you need to use another variable that has your new values for cart (cartArray in this example).

```
   const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

   // Add Product to cart 
  const addProduct = (product) => {
  let cartArray= [...cart]
  
const exist = cartArray.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
if (exist) {
  cartArray = cartArray.map((x) =>
      x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
    ) 
  
  setDoc(
    doc(firebaseFirestore, "users", user?.uid!),
    { cart: cartArray },
    { merge: true }
  )
    .then(() => {console.log("done") ; setCart([...cartArray]) })
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error"));
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
  chakraToast({
    status: "success",
    title: `Product updated with a new quantity`,
    isClosable: true,
    containerStyle: {
      fontSize: "12.5px",
    },
    variant: "subtle",
    position: "bottom-right",
  });
} else {
  cartArray = [...cart, { ...product, qty: 1 }];
  setDoc(
    doc(firebaseFirestore, "users", user?.uid!),
    { cart: arrayUnion(...cartArray) },
    { merge: true }
  )
    .then(() => { console.log("done") ; setCart([...cartArray]) })
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error"));
  chakraToast({
    status: "success",
    title: "Product added successfully",
    isClosable: true,
    containerStyle: {
      fontSize: "12.5px",
    },
    variant: "subtle",
    position: "bottom-right",
  });
  console.log("Cart First Instance", cart);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
}
 };
```